# Dynamically add css class to <tr> tag

Tags: javascript

I've three predefined class for `<tr class="dynamicCSS">` tag. Those classes shall come one after another. Like -

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="dynamicCSS"> //classA
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="dynamicCSS"> //classB
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="dynamicCSS"> //classC
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="dynamicCSS"> //repeat the above 
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: IDs are unique, you should use classes instead.

Comment: My question has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to add classes to tr elements would be to use [jQuery.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
jQuery("tr").addClass("myClass");
```

The selector passed into the jQuery call can also [select nth children](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), for example to add a class to every third `tr` element:

```
jQuery("tr:nth-child(3n)").addClass("classC");
```

Comment: if i want to use it for a specific table?

Comment: @SKPaul: If you've got a reference to the table element already, you could find its children using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/): `jQuery(table).find("tr")`, or if it has an id, you could use an id selector directly: `jQuery("#myTable tr")`. I'd definitely recommend looking into a library like jQuery if you've not heard of it, since it makes repetitive things like adding and removing classes clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: I'm using as below. Is it ok?

$("#distsummery tr:nth-child(3n+3)").addClass("success");

$("#distsummery tr:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("info");

$("#distsummery tr:nth-child(3n+1)").addClass("error");

Comment: That looks good, nice and succinct. The main difficulty with my suggestion is that it won't handle nested tables very well, nor dynamically updated tables. (You could use child selectors to fix the nested table issue, but watch out for `tbody` elements which could the the direct children of tables.) If you can get away with using just css, angabriel's answer would be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way of identifying the rows you want to add the classes to. (You can't use the same `id` value over and over again as you have in your question, so that won't work, but you could give them *different* `id` values.)

Once you have a way of identifying the `tr` elements in question, it's just a matter of setting the `className` property of those elements.

For instance, in your example you've identified the second, third, and fourth rows in the table. Assuming the table has the `id` `"myTable"`, you can get the table's rows from its [`rows` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6156016), which is an [`HTMLCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) you can index into starting with `0`:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.rows[1].className = "classA"; // second row
table.rows[2].className = "classB"; // third row
table.rows[3].className = "classC"; // fourth row
```

Note that that will wipe out any previous class the rows had. If you want to *add* a class, use `+= " classX"` (note the space):

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.rows[1].className += " classA"; // second row
table.rows[2].className += " classB"; // third row
table.rows[3].className += " classC"; // fourth row
```

In the above I've restricted myself to DOM functions that are present in just about all browsers, even older ones. On [all major current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), rather than `getElementById` and the `rows` collection, you can use `querySelector` with any valid CSS selector expression that will identify the row you want to add a class to. You don't need it, necessarily, for what you've described, but it's good to know about it (and its cousin `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of matching elements whereas `querySelector` returns just the first matching element).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for the nth:child css selector *1

For your example you can fiddle with it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/95N4E/

```
.myTable tr:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: gray;
}
.myTable tr:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.myTable tr:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color: steelblue;
}
```

And read how it works here:

*1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child